# Rails4 How to do a outer join with mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 table. Company has one or many Account.

I want to list all the Companies, at the same time list all the accounts in the company. But sometimes a company has no account yet.

Basically i need.

```
Company Name | Account Name | Mobile

Company 1 | John | 91234567

Company 1 | Peter | 91234567

Company 2 | Nil | Nil
```

I know what i need is an outer join, but apparently mysql doesnt support, then i found out that i can use union, but i'm not sure how to do that in rails. my current code is

```
Company.joins(:accounts)
```

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `Company.includes(:accounts)`

Comment: tried that. includes account will only return each single company and i cant list them in the rows if the company have more than 1 account

Answer (score 0):

```
Company.joins("LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = companies.account_id")
```

Or

```
Company.find(:all,
   joins: "LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = companies.account_id",
   select: "companies.name, accounts.id, accounts.mobile ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use includes and references to accomplish this:

```
Company.includes(:accounts).references(:accounts)
```